# Desugaring the $colon$colon token

Tags: scala

When used as an expression, and when used as a pattern, `h::t` is desugared into two different things. This makes total sense as when it's used in an expression, we want to apply the `::` method to `t` with the parameter `h`, i.e. `t.$colon$colon(h)`; whereas when it's used in a match case, we want to recognize it as `$colon$colon(h,t)`, i.e. a case class pattern.

In a fit of idle curiosity, I'm wondering what it is about the context that results in these two different interpretations. In the case of the expression, I understand that `::` is a right-associative method, but how does it go from `h::t` to `$colon$colon(h,t)` in the other situation?

Edit: adding source code to illustrate the two different contexts:

```
  def decode(xs: List[Int]): Unit =
    xs match {
      case Nil =>
      case h :: t => println(h::t); decode(t)
    }
```

Comment: `$colon$colon`? You mean `::`?

Comment: @cHao Well, the actual :: token is desugared into $colon$colon but otherwise, they are more or less interchangeable.

Comment: Please include small code examples that illustrate your contention that `h::t` is translated "into two different things."

Comment: @jwvh I did provide the desugared code samples (although a simplified them a little). I will edit the original question and give an example of the contexts I'm describing. Sorry, I didn't think there would be any difficulty in interpreting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by jwvh, your question is not clear and allow various interpretations. Anyway I'll try to answer some of the more obvious ones:

**`::` vs `$colon$colon`**

Unlike many more traditional languages Scala allows defining custom operators including almost any symbols such as "`:`". On the other hand Scala is compiled to some other target platforms (such as JVM) that do not allow such symbols in names of methods. To work this around a typical solution is for compiler to automatically transform "prohibited" symbols into some rare but valid sequence. `$colon` is just such sequence for `:`. So `::` transforms to `$colon$colon`.

**Infix notation**

Another important point for friendly custom operators is allowing [infix notation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/operators.html) and it also works for any method with just one argument rather than just operators. For example you may also write `list map func` which will be translated to `list.map(func)`

**Pattern matching**

Scala design for pattern matching is explicitly extensible. It means that you may write a code such that pattern matching will work for your custom classes. And the code you need to write is an [extractor object with `unapply` (or `unapplySeq`) method](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html) (see also [this guide](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html) for less trivial examples). Moreover for `case class`es the compiler automatically generates proper `unapply`. And if you look at the code, you may see that `scala.collection.immutable.::` is actually a `case class`.

Comment: @Phasmid, if something else is not clear, you should probably make your question(s) more explicit.

Comment: Thanks. I apologize for the lack of clarity. I thought it would be clear. Your elaboration interesting although in each case, I already noted briefly what you expanded on. I guess what I'm really looking for is what in the sense of a production element (or type of Parser[T]) follows the *case* keyword and precedes the *=>* symbol?

Comment: @Phasmid, Have you read the linked articles about the `unapply` method and "extractor object"? This is how it actually works (you may also see [Section 8.1.8 of the language spec](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#extractor-patterns)). I'm not sure what there is unclear for you.

Comment: thanks for the reference to the language spec. I should have been looking at that already, as I knew that ultimately, that would be the answer. I think I get it: a Stable Identifier where the type matches that of what is being matched. I still don't *quite* get where it chooses this form instead of treating it as an expression--which also results in the appropriate type. But I will keep looking at it. I'm sure I'll get it. And, yes, naturally, I've read the other references you mention (several times).

Comment: @Phasmid, It seems just impossible to fish out of you any explicit description of what the question really is. It is really hard to answer a question without knowing it! My next guess is: "how the compilers knows that `case SomeCaseClass(some params)` should be treated as attempt to `unapply`?". If you look at [Syntax Summary](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/13-syntax-summary.html), you may see that 1. pattern matching context can be notice by being inside a `match` clause or `BlockExpr`. 2. The only other usage of the word `case` requires the next word to be `class` or `object`

Comment: OK, I got it. Thanks for your help.